# Unable to Post in Chatter on Opportunity record Page

Tags: lightning, chatter

Chatter component on Lightning Page Layout on Opportunity doesn't contain the Chatter actions: Post/File/etc. As a result, our users are not able to post on Opportunities (or any other record). However, they can post in Global Chatter.

I can confirm that:

a) The "Enable Actions in the Publisher" checkbox is ticked

b) The "Global Publisher Layout" has the necessary buttons indeed

What is missing to enable them to collaborate on individual records (e.g. Opportunities)?

Many thanks in advance,

Ed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to show those action in Chatter component on the Opportunity record page, You need to add those action in page layout in the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section.

[image]

Once you added those action, make sure you have the chatter component added in Lightning page for that object record.

You will find those as follows:-

[image]

To know more about how the action works in Lightning Experience, Go through the following trailhead module:-

[Understand How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions)

In terms of what is not available in Lightning when compared to classic, You need to go through this:- [Chatter: What’s Different or Not Available in Lightning Experience](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_collaboration.htm&type=5)

**Chatter Publisher**

Users can compose these post types in Lightning Experience:

1. Text posts, with or without a file attachment
2. Polls
3. Questions
4. Announcements in group feeds

Other post types, like Thanks, aren’t currently supported.

Comment: Hi Sanket Kumar, as I've explained in my question, the necessary actions are already on the publisher layout. The Actions are available on the Global Publisher, but NOT on the record. This is the problem I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: When I'm adding the Chatter Publisher component to the Opportunity Lightning Page Layout and select Type = Global, then the Actions appear as expected, but when I select Publisher Type = Record, then the Actions disappear.

Comment: Do the actions are added in Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section on page layout of Opportunity? Publisher layout are different than what i am talking.

Comment: Hi Sanket, you're right. Before I had the actions added to the Publisher Global layout, but not the opportunity. Now that I've added the actions to the Opportunity as well, it all works. Thanks